# Can I add Divine Favor damage to Two Weapon Fighting?

Tags: spells, dnd-5e, damage

If I'm a War Cleric, and I cast Divine Favor on myself and I use two light weapons and they both hit, do I add the extra damage twice since both weapons hit, or just once since both weapons are part of one attack?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Both

*Divine favor* adds to all weapon damage rolls; every successful hit with a weapon gets the bonus damage.

Comment: It's not all damage rolls, it's every hit. i.e. if you multi-class as a rogue, you don't do W+1d8 + Sneak Attack + 1d8.

Comment: @GMNoob Sneak Attack is bonus damage, i.e. your damage roll (singular) includes it. It is not a separate damage roll itself.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely.

> You gain a +1 bonus to attack rolls and damage rolls until your concentration is broken, but for no longer than 1 minute.

That's a bonus to *your* damage rolls, just like increasing your strength gives you a bonus to damage rolls. It applies to every roll.

Comment: "You gain a +1 bonus to attack rolls and damage rolls until your concentration is broken, but for no longer than 1 minute." Could you be referring to Magic Weapon?

Comment: I might have been, unfortunately. I don't have copies of the latest 5th edition work, and pulled what I could find off the internet, mostly just to ensure the rules didn't VASTLY change from what I expected.

Answer (score 1):

*Attack Action* is different from *attack*.  You are not doing one attack.  You are doing two attacks in one attack action.

Many extra action features targets the attack **action**, such as Extra Attack, Two Weapons Fighting, Flurry of blows, or Archery Master feat. They do not apply to all attacks, for example they are not triggered when you cast an attack spell or use your reaction to do an opportunity attack.

Many extra damage and defense features targets **attack**(s).  When something says when you hit or miss, it also is in this camp.  Bless, Divine Favor, Improved Divine Smite, Sneak Attack, Heavy Armor Master feat, enhancement bonus etc. all applies to *individual attacks*.  They applies to *any* applicable attacks.

So, your Divine Favor bonus applies to *every weapon hit* (not every damage roll).